# AJAX call not being executed for some users browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an issue where my JQuery AJAX call is not being executed for some users browser. Its working for most of the users. Does antivirus software/firewall or browser extension prevents the execution of AJAX call or prevents the return data from AJAX.

Does browser with disabled localStorage and/or sessionStorage prevent my JS function from executing ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            
           sessionStorage.setItem("primaryId", 312312);
           CheckData(312312);

            function CheckData(primaryId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CheckDataList","ControllerA")',
                data: "{'PrimaryID':'" + primaryId+ "' }",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "Json",
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.length) {
                        var url = '@Url.Action("Index","ControllerB")';
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });

        }

</script>
```

Comment: Disabling localStorage or sessionStorage should not directly prevent your ajax from executing. However, if there is an error while you are setting the item in session storage, it might throw and then your CheckData() call doesn't get to execute.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an issue where my JQuery AJAX call is not being executed for
> some users browser. Its working for most of the users. Does antivirus
> software/firewall or browser extension prevents the execution of AJAX
> call or prevents the return data from AJAX.

Well, there might be numerous reasons when JavaScript or jQuery request or in particular ajax request might not be executed and its common sometimes depending on browser settings or even machine configuration, because sometimes,  browser may disable script or due to security issues a machine might treat ajax request as security vulnerabilities, so we should check or verify all the prerequisites.

First of all, double check your browser settings if there is any restriction on  javascript execution. For instance, you can check following configuration  in your browser:

Chorme browser settings:

[image]

Edge browser settings:

[image]

**Note:** Make sure, the users where you have observed your ajax request getting failed, has no restriction on above settings.

Check network trace:

Your browser network trace will always provide you some extra information regarding your request details,so please check your network log and console. Because, depending on error code, you can decided easily whats going on. You can check properly in the browser's console and/or network tools. You should be able to retrieve the actual HTTP status code and the response given by the server (if any).

[image]

> Does antivirus software/firewall or browser extension prevents the
> execution of AJAX call or prevents the return data from AJAX.

Of course they do. Let's say, if you are getting `"403 Forbidden"` indicates that this is related to the server configuration.

Most likely, some security software or firewall on the server does not like something in
the HTTP request that is sent from the browser to the server when clicking the Save button. To find out more about this, you’d have to check your server’s error log files, maybe together with your webhost.
Then, the server configuration would have to be relaxed so that it no longer raises false positives.

Apart from that, For the `400 error`, it might related to  the [Antiforgery request.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0#antiforgery-in-aspnet-core-1) The Razor Pages is automatically protected from [XSRF/CSRF.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0) You should set the XSRF-TOKEN when you want to use the ajax to send request in razor page.

In addition to this, [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) may also cause ajax request failure.

**Note:** In order to checking ajax request failure, you would need to check above configuration and setting depending on the scenario.